# HTML5 footer not working in IE

Tags: html, footer

So I'm not sure what I did however my footer won't stay at the bottom anymore after I placed the images from our festival in this page. I've tried everything I could think of including making it a div aside from using the HTML 5  tag but IE just doesn't want to play nice! Ugh. [Here is my site](http://oooysterfestival.com/index2.html). The footer is great on all pages but the index2.html page.

HTML

```
<footer class="clearfix">
<a href="events.html">Events</a> | <a href="wineries.html">Wineries</a> | <a href="restaurants.html">Restaurants</a> | <a href="golf.html">Golf Courses</a> | <a href="index.html">Home</a>
<a href="http://ambergoodwin.com/" title="Graphic & Web Design | www.ambergoodwin.com" id="ambergoodwin">Amber Goodwin | Creative &amp; Fresh Designs</a>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer { width: 100%; height: 130px; position: relative; top: 600px; background-color: #b14a0f;  font-size: 1.2em; padding-top: 30px; color: #721501; text-align: center; clear: both; }
```

I just don't understand how this looks great on all pages but this newest one. 
Any help or advice on IE is great!

*** UPDATE ***

I do have the shim in my code and now I've just made my footer into a regular ol div but it still is acting strange. It's like it's ignoring my new styles..... Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: IE8. 9 works fine http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/

Comment: @ambrelasweb, Please accept "your" Answer so this Question is resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. So I fixed it. Still not sure wtf was going on with IE but I ended up having to make a new stylesheet but after every new change I had to link it to another stylesheet name. Has anyone ever heard of IE acting like that??

Thanks for the users who posted comments! After a few hours of pulling my hair out I did what ever would work to get it working for IE and the most important thing is it paid off.

Comment: Sounds like browser cache... http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache ... also this is not really an answer to the question

Comment: @ambrelasweb, Please accept your Answer so this Question is resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IE8 and bellow don't support html5 natively. You need to use compatibility utilities such as [html5shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/)

Answer (score 1):

Your `<nav id="main-navigation">` element isn't being closed properly. This may well be disrupting your layout.

Answer (score 0):

haha yea you have to code for IE, especially with a site like that since most of the sheep out there use it.

But yea just use a div element and style it accordingly.

Comment: Please see updated question. I had tried this before asking the question however it's like nothing I do will work.. Any help you could provide I would be very appreciative! I'm pulling my hair out with this one.